# Remove (merge) SQL Servers' database secondary data file

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-restore, data-files

I have a database backup for which SQL Server Management Studio says that it has three files in it: an `.mdf` file, an `.ndf` file and one `.ldf` file. This secondary data file (the `.ndf` one) was created for no obvious reason, so I want to remove it altogether (without losing data, of course), preferably during while the database is being restored from the backup.

Is this at all doable?

Comment: The purpose of an NDF is to distribute file IO. If you live server has NDF's don't tinker with the schema. Why does the NDF bother you ?

Comment: @Hassan It was created just to overcome NTFS volume fragmentation and it does not have other reasons for its existence. While I agree that NDFs are good, carelessly created NDFs are evil.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, found a solution.

First back up the database.

Execute this:

```
USE database_name;
```

Then execute this, and replace `logical_ndf_file_name` with the logical name of your NDF file (which you can easily find out via Database->Properties_Files):

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('logical_ndf_file_name', EMPTYFILE);
ALTER DATABASE database_name REMOVE FILE logical_ndf_file_name;
```

Comment: was there data in your file ? and if so how long did it take , and was the DB live ?

Comment: @Hassan NDF was about 8 Gb, while MDF was around 60 Gb. It took about 20 minutes all in all. Not sure about what you mean by "live". I didn't take it offline, but no queries were run against it either.

Comment: interesting information. By Live I meant production use or customer facing.

Comment: @Hassan I doubt that it was available for production use.

Comment: To add some clarification here, 'ndf_file_name' in the line of code above refers to the logical file name, not the physical. This was not immediately clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the empty followed by ndf drop during produciton load successfully. I think it is important to run the drop ndf in the same transaction as the empty to ensure the database doesn't try to write to the file you are deleting, but then after an empty the database marks the files unusable, evidenced by attempting another empty shorty after.